# convert a not-full binary search tree to full binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have a trouble in full binary search tree
How can I convert a a not-full binary search tree to full binary search tree, such as this example:

I have a structure of Node in tree:

struct Node
{
 
    int key;
 
    Node* left,*right;

};

and I have a binary tree

--------18

------/----\

-----16---19

-----/-\----\

----8--17--20

---/-----------

--7------------

It's not a full binary search tree, it just a binary tree.
and I want to convert this tree to full binary search tree like:

---------17

-------/-----\

------8------19

-----/-\-----/---\

----7-16--18---20

Please help me to solve it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach which works if the number of nodes in the binary tree has enough nodes to construct a full tree, i.e. number of nodes is equal to 1 or 3 or 7 or 15 or ... 2^n -1, with a positive integer n, is to read the tree into a vector and sort it. Then the sorted vector can be passed to a well know algorithm described [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-array-to-balanced-bst/). The idea is that the root of the BST is in the middle of the vector and the left child of the root node which is the root of the left subtree will be in the middle of the left half of the sorted vector (the same applies to the right node and the right half of the vector).

**Please note:** If the number of nodes in the binary tree (your input) is not equal to 2^n -1 then it is not possible to construct a **full** binary (search) tree, because you don't have the right number of nodes available. However, if you are allowed to add additional nodes, i.e. nodes that are not in the binary tree (you haven't said something about this in your question) the code below also works, but you would need to add additional nodes to the sorted vector (e.g. incrementally growing numbers at the end).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int key;
    Node* left,*right;
};


/*
 * Construct a tree like this and return a pointer
 * to the root node
 */
//--------18
//------/----\
//-----16---19
//-----/-\----\
//----8--17--20
//---/-----------
//--7------------
Node* constructExampleTree();

/*
 * Place all nodes which are part of the tree
 * mounted under 'node' (including 'node') into 'vec'.
 */
void placeIntoVector(vector<int>& vec, Node* node);

/*
 * Print the tree rooted under 'node' in order
 */
void printInOder(Node* node);

/*
 * Delete all nodes rooted under 'node' in post order
 */
void deleteInPostOrder(Node* node);

/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the
   given data and NULL left and right pointers. */
Node* newNode(int data);

/* A function that constructs Balanced Binary Search Tree from a sorted array
 *
 * Algorithm taken from: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-array-to-balanced-bst/
 * */
Node* sortedArrayToBST(vector<int>& arr, int start, int end)
{
    /* Base Case */
    if (start > end)
      return NULL;

    /* Get the middle element and make it root */
    int mid = (start + end)/2;
    Node *root = newNode(arr[mid]);

    /* Recursively construct the left subtree and make it
       left child of root */
    root->left =  sortedArrayToBST(arr, start, mid-1);

    /* Recursively construct the right subtree and make it
       right child of root */
    root->right = sortedArrayToBST(arr, mid+1, end);

    return root;
}

int main (){

    Node* root = constructExampleTree();

    vector<int> vec;
    placeIntoVector(vec, root);

    sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());

    int counter = static_cast<int>( vec.size());
    Node *bstRoot = sortedArrayToBST(vec, 0, counter -1);

    // Printing a BST in order will give us a sorted output
    printInOder(bstRoot);

    deleteInPostOrder(root);
    deleteInPostOrder(bstRoot);

    return 0;
}

Node* constructExampleTree() {

    /*
     * Level 1 and 2
     */
    Node* eighteen = new Node();
    eighteen->key = 18;
    eighteen->left = NULL;
    eighteen->right= NULL;

    Node* sixteen = new Node();
    sixteen->key = 16;
    sixteen->left = NULL;
    sixteen->right= NULL;

    Node* nineteen = new Node();
    nineteen->key = 19;
    nineteen->left = NULL;
    nineteen->right= NULL;

    eighteen->left = sixteen;
    eighteen->right = nineteen;

    /*
     * Level 3
     */
    Node* eight = new Node();
    eight->key = 8;
    eight->left = NULL;
    eight->right= NULL;

    Node* seventeen = new Node();
    seventeen->key = 17;
    seventeen->left = NULL;
    seventeen->right= NULL;

    Node* twenty = new Node();
    twenty->key = 20;
    twenty->left = NULL;
    twenty->right= NULL;

    sixteen->left = eight;
    sixteen->right = seventeen;

    nineteen->right = twenty;

    /*
     * Level 4
     */
    Node* seven = new Node();
    seven->key = 7;
    seven->left = NULL;
    seven->right= NULL;

    eight->left = seven;

    return eighteen;
}

void placeIntoVector(vector<int>& vec, Node* node){
    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    placeIntoVector(vec, node->left);
    vec.push_back(node->key);
    placeIntoVector(vec, node->right);
}

void printInOder(Node* node){
    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    printInOder(node->left);
    cout << node->key << " ";
    printInOder(node->right);
}

void deleteInPostOrder(Node* node){
    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    deleteInPostOrder(node->left);
    deleteInPostOrder(node->right);
    delete node;
}


/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the
   given data and NULL left and right pointers. */
Node* newNode(int data)
{
    Node* node = new Node();
    node->key = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;

    return node;
}
```